# Spring Aspects not executing but aspect was scanned while starting web sphere server

Tags: spring-aop

why my Aspect not executing eventhough aspect class was scanned while loading by spring container.

My Aspect class as below:

```
package com.qmp.aspect;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import com.qmp.data.addressstd.request.AddressStdRequest;
import com.qmp.data.autorate.request.AutoRateRequest;
import com.qmp.data.brightline.request.BrightLineRequest;
import com.qmp.data.email.request.SendEmailRequest;
import com.qmp.data.retrievequote.request.RetrieveQuoteRequest;
import com.qmp.data.savequote.request.SaveQuoteRequest;
import com.qmp.data.vin.request.VINRequest;

@Component
@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class QMPLoggingAspect {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(QMPLoggingAspect.class
            .getName());
    private static long vinrequestCount = 0;
    private static long addresStdrequestCount = 0;
    private static long saveQuoterequestCount = 0;
    private static long retQuoterequestCount = 0;
    private static long autoRaterequestCount = 0;
    private static long brightLinerequestCount = 0;
    private static long emailServicerequestCount = 0;

    @Around("execution(* com.qmp.service.QMPService.sendEmail(..)) && args(emailRequest)")
    public void logAroundEmailService(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            SendEmailRequest emailRequest) {
        System.out.println("venkat======================>");
        ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Email Service Execution Starts:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Email Service Execution Ends:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        log.debug("Email Service Elapsed milliseconds==>"
                + (lEndTime - lStartTime) + " :: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : "" + " Request Number==>" + emailServicerequestCount);
        emailServicerequestCount++;

    }

    @Around("execution(* com.qmp.service.QMPService.doVinLookUp(..)) && args(vinRequest)")
    public void logAroundVinLookup(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            VINRequest vinRequest) {
        ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("VIN Look up Execution Starts:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("VIN Look up Execution Ends:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        log.debug("VIN Look up Elapsed milliseconds==>"
                + (lEndTime - lStartTime) + " :: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : "" + " Request Number==>" + vinrequestCount);
        vinrequestCount++;

    }

    @Around("execution(* com.qmp.service.QMPService.doBrightLine(..)) && args(brightLineRequest)")
    public void logAroundBrightline(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            BrightLineRequest brightLineRequest) {
        ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Brightline Execution Starts:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Brightline Execution Ends:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        log.debug("Brightline Elapsed milliseconds==>"
                + (lEndTime - lStartTime) + " :: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : "" + " Request Number==>" + brightLinerequestCount);
        brightLinerequestCount++;

    }

    @Around("execution(* com.qmp.service.QMPService.performAutoRate(..)) && args(autoRateRequest)")
    public void logAroundAutoRate(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            AutoRateRequest autoRateRequest) {
        ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Auto rate Execution Starts:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Auto rate Execution Ends:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        log.debug("Auto rate Elapsed milliseconds==>" + (lEndTime - lStartTime)
                + " :: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session.getId()
                : "" + " Request Number==>" + autoRaterequestCount);
        autoRaterequestCount++;

    }

    @Around("execution(* com.qmp.service.QMPService.performAddressStandardization(..)) && args(addressStdRequest)")
    public void logAroundAddressStd(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            AddressStdRequest addressStdRequest) {
        ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Address Std Execution Starts:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Address Std Execution Ends:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        log.debug("Address Std Elapsed milliseconds==>"
                + (lEndTime - lStartTime) + " :: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : "" + " Request Number==>" + addresStdrequestCount);
        addresStdrequestCount++;

    }

    @Around("execution(* com.qmp.service.QMPService.retrieveQuote(..)) && args(retrieveQuoteRequest)")
    public void logAroundRetrieveQuote(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            RetrieveQuoteRequest retrieveQuoteRequest) {
        ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Retrieve Quote Execution Starts:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Retrieve Quote Execution Ends:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        log.debug("Retrieve Quote Elapsed milliseconds==>"
                + (lEndTime - lStartTime) + " :: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : "" + " Request Number==>" + retQuoterequestCount);
        retQuoterequestCount++;

    }

    @Around("execution(* com.qmp.service.QMPService.saveQuote(..)) && args(saveQuoteRequest)")
    public void logAroundSaveQuote(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            SaveQuoteRequest saveQuoteRequest) {
        ServletRequestAttributes t = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest req = t.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Save Quote Execution Starts:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.debug("Save Quote Execution Ends:: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : ""
                + " - "
                + "TimeStamp:::"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                        .format(new Date()));
        log.debug("Save Quote Elapsed milliseconds==>"
                + (lEndTime - lStartTime) + " :: SessionId::  - " + session != null ? session
                .getId() : "" + " Request Number==>" + saveQuoterequestCount);
        saveQuoterequestCount++;

    }

}

applicationContext.xml : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.qmp.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.qmp.service.email" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.qmp.util" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.qmp.service.brightline" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.qmp.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.qmp.aspect" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
</beans>
```

Interface : QMPService.java

```
package com.qmp.service;

import com.farmers.ffq.exceptions.BaseFFQ3Exception;
import com.farmers.pla.service.PlaServiceException;
import com.qmp.data.addressstd.request.AddressStdRequest;
import com.qmp.data.addressstd.response.AddressStdResponse;
import com.qmp.data.autorate.request.AutoRateRequest;
import com.qmp.data.autorate.response.AutoRateResponse;
import com.qmp.data.brightline.request.BrightLineRequest;
import com.qmp.data.brightline.response.BrightLineResponse;
import com.qmp.data.email.request.SendEmailRequest;
import com.qmp.data.email.response.SendEmailResp;
import com.qmp.data.retrievequote.request.RetrieveQuoteRequest;
import com.qmp.data.retrievequote.response.RetrieveQuoteResponse;
import com.qmp.data.savequote.request.SaveQuoteRequest;
import com.qmp.data.savequote.response.SaveQuoteResponse;
import com.qmp.data.vin.request.VINRequest;
import com.qmp.data.vin.response.VINResponse;

public interface QMPService {

    public VINResponse doVinLookUp(VINRequest vinRequest);

    public BrightLineResponse doBrightLine(BrightLineRequest brightLineRequest);

    public AutoRateResponse performAutoRate(AutoRateRequest autoRateRequest);

    public AddressStdResponse performAddressStandardization(
            AddressStdRequest addressStdRequest) throws BaseFFQ3Exception,
            PlaServiceException;

    public RetrieveQuoteResponse retrieveQuote(
            RetrieveQuoteRequest retrieveQuoteRequest)
            throws BaseFFQ3Exception, PlaServiceException;

    public SaveQuoteResponse saveQuote(SaveQuoteRequest saveQuoteRequest)
            throws BaseFFQ3Exception, PlaServiceException;

    public SendEmailResp sendEmail(SendEmailRequest emailRequest);
}
```

Implimentation class :

QMPServiceMgr.java
//I have implimented all methods in this class.
Controller class :

```
package com.qmp.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.farmers.ffq.exceptions.BaseFFQ3Exception;
import com.farmers.pla.service.PlaServiceException;
import com.qmp.data.addressstd.request.AddressStdRequest;
import com.qmp.data.addressstd.response.AddressStdResponse;
import com.qmp.data.autorate.request.AutoRateRequest;
import com.qmp.data.autorate.response.AutoRateResponse;
import com.qmp.data.brightline.request.BrightLineRequest;
import com.qmp.data.brightline.response.BrightLineResponse;
import com.qmp.data.email.request.SendEmailRequest;
import com.qmp.data.email.response.SendEmailResp;
import com.qmp.data.retrievequote.request.RetrieveQuoteRequest;
import com.qmp.data.retrievequote.response.RetrieveQuoteResponse;
import com.qmp.data.savequote.request.SaveQuoteRequest;
import com.qmp.data.savequote.response.SaveQuoteResponse;
import com.qmp.data.vin.request.VINRequest;
import com.qmp.data.vin.response.VINResponse;
import com.qmp.service.QMPService;

@RestController
public class QMPController {
    @Autowired
    private QMPService qmpService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/vin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public VINResponse doVinLookUp(@RequestBody VINRequest vinRequest) {
        return qmpService.doVinLookUp(vinRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/brightline", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public BrightLineResponse performBrightLine(
            @RequestBody BrightLineRequest brightLineRequest) {
        return qmpService.doBrightLine(brightLineRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/autoRate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public AutoRateResponse performAutoRate(
            @RequestBody AutoRateRequest autoRateRequest) {
        return qmpService.performAutoRate(autoRateRequest);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/address", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public AddressStdResponse performAddrStandardization(
            @RequestBody AddressStdRequest addressStdRequest)
            throws PlaServiceException, BaseFFQ3Exception {
        AddressStdResponse addressStdResponse = null;
        return addressStdResponse = qmpService
                .performAddressStandardization(addressStdRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/retQuote", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RetrieveQuoteResponse retrieveQuote(
            @RequestBody RetrieveQuoteRequest retrieveQuoteRequest)
            throws PlaServiceException, BaseFFQ3Exception {
        return qmpService.retrieveQuote(retrieveQuoteRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveQuote", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public SaveQuoteResponse saveQuote(
            @RequestBody SaveQuoteRequest saveQuoteRequest)
            throws PlaServiceException, BaseFFQ3Exception {
        return qmpService.saveQuote(saveQuoteRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/comnms/v1/emailNotifications", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public SendEmailResp sendEmail(
            @RequestBody SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest) {
        return qmpService.sendEmail(sendEmailRequest);
    }

}
```

While loading it is verifying all syntax's and going good but not sure why logging Aspect not injecting while executing Rest Service.

Any assistance appreciated.

Note : i tried sample program using same configuration in  Tomcat working good. But not sure why it is not executing in my Project which is running on Websphere.

Thanks,
Venkat.